# How to transfer recorded audio ATRAC3® files from a Sony MZ-NH900 to a PC?

Tags: file-transfer, drm, audio-conversion, atrac

I have a Sony MZ-NH900 mini-disc reader and recorder. I had recorded (using a microphone) audio files back in the past, and I would like to transfer these files to a PC now. 
[image: Sony MZ-NH900]

I had to use a software called [SonicStage® 4.3](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=MZNH900&upd_id=2524&os_group_id=13) to transfer the files back in the old time. **The problem is the files are ATRAC3® and they are kind of copy-protected**, which means I can listen to them on the mini-disc but cannot transfer them to my computer since I do not have the DRM file telling SonicStage that I really have the copy rights on these files.

Since time has past, maybe there is a solution now. Is there a way to get back these files, which I own since I have recorded them myself?

Otherwise, I will resort to trying to plug the output of the mini-disc reader on a sound card and record them again, but with a loss of quality I guess.

Comment: @wonea Per http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212, questions about DRM removal are permitted as long as they're not a clear call for warez and their likes.

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog [post](http://forums.sonyinsider.com/topic/27640-sony-connect-bypass/?p=181077), there's an application called [HiMDRenderer](http://forums.sonyinsider.com/topic/22268-new-himdrenderer-100-beta-4-updated-26022008/) ([Homepage](http://www.marcnetsystem.co.uk/)) which can read Sony Connect files and convert them to MP3.  [Sony Connect files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Connect) should be in a copy protected ATRAC format, similar to yours. I would say ATRAC is also a [lossy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format like MP3, so when converting these files, try using the highest encoding settings so to avoid any further loss of quality.

Comment: ATRAC is not lossless.  ATRAC is simply designed to have low computational requirements (and hence produce longer battery life on devices which use it), at the cost of larger file sizes.